# calling function of a smart contract through another smart contract

Tags: contract-development, nft, external-function

i have 2 smart contracts:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "./../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract HNFT is ERC721 {
    uint price;
    address issuer;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        issuer = msg.sender;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, 0);
    }

    function getIssuer() external view returns (address) {
        return issuer;
    }

    function getPrice() external view returns (uint) {
        return price;
    }

    function setPrice(uint _price) external {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(tx.origin, 0),
            "The transaction origin caller is not allowed to perform this action"
        );
        price = _price;
    }

    function transferToken(address to) external payable {
        require(msg.value == price, "not enough value provided");
        super.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, 0);
    }

    function burn() external {
        _isApprovedOrOwner(tx.origin, 0);
        _burn(0);
    }
}
```

and another contract, the main contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;
import "./HNFT.sol";

contract MainSmartContract {
    address private owner;
    address[] private issuedItems;
    address[] private inSellItems;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getIssuedItems() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        return issuedItems;
    }

    function getInSellItems() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        return inSellItems;
    }

    function SetPriceAndSell(address NFTAddress, uint _price) external {
        if (!containsAddress(NFTAddress, inSellItems)) {
            addNewInSellItem(NFTAddress);
            if (!containsAddress(NFTAddress, issuedItems))
                addNewIssuedItem(NFTAddress);
        }
        HNFT _HNFT = HNFT(NFTAddress);
        _HNFT.setPrice(_price);
    }

    function Buy(address NFTAddress, address to) external payable {
        HNFT _HNFT = HNFT(NFTAddress);
        _HNFT.transferToken{value: msg.value}(to);
    }

    function CheckValidity(address NFTAddress) external view returns (bool) {
        if (containsAddress(NFTAddress, issuedItems)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function burn(address NFTAddress) external {
        if (removeElement(inSellItems, NFTAddress)) {
            HNFT _HNFT = HNFT(NFTAddress);
            _HNFT.burn();
        } else {
            revert("The NFT does not exists in the sell market");
        }
    }

    function addNewInSellItem(address newItem) internal {
        inSellItems.push(newItem);
    }

    function addNewIssuedItem(address newItem) internal {
        issuedItems.push(newItem);
    }

    function containsAddress(
        address _address,
        address[] memory array
    ) internal pure returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if (_address == array[index]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function removeElement(
        address[] storage array,
        address elem
    ) internal returns (bool) {
        uint _index = 0;
        for (uint256 index = 1; index < array.length + 1; index++) {
            if (elem == array[index - 1]) {
                _index = index;
            }
        }
        if (_index != 0) {
            array[_index] == array[array.length - 1];
            array.pop();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the main smart contract should call the HNFT smart contract function by knowing only its address but when i try to send a transaction to setPrice() i get an error about a revert on the EVM. Debugging i think that the problem is the instantiation of the HNFT smart contract that i use to make the call. how should it be done?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (/tmp/.mount_gana.....